# Doing simple malloc/free within dispatch_async causes memory leak on iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ios9, grand-central-dispatch

I just got a memory leak in my code after I updated my iPad to iOS9, which worked fine on iOS8 and iOS7.

I have an anonymous thread created by the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [self threadWork];
});
```

And the thread does a pair of malloc/free call like this:

```
- (void)threadWork {
    // Create a serial queue.
    dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

    while (1) {
        // Do a simple malloc.
        int *foo = (int *)malloc(1024);

        // Do free in serial queue.
        dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
            free(foo);
        });

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0 / 60.0];
    }
}
```

This routing will keep the memory usage increasing and finally crashes device on iOS 9. The problem also happened on new/delete in Objective-C++.

---

I found some other way to do this without memory leak:

1. Use main queue or global queue to instead the serial queue.
2. Create concurrent queue instead the serial queue.
3. Use [NSThread detachNewThreadWithSelector:toTarget:withObject:] to create the thread instead GCD.

I don't understand why this simple routing causes this problem.
I've searched this on google but found nothing.

How can I do this with keeping serial queue and GCD anonymous thread?

---

Update:

I tried to put NSLog commands in my code to figure out when will the malloc/free be called. The result shows that both of them are called immediately and come in pair. I also tried to slow the thread down to once per second, but the problem still here.

The test code of thread:

```
- (void)threadWork {
    uint64_t mallocCount = 0;
    __block uint64_t freeCount = 0;
    dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
    while (1) {
        void *test = malloc(1024);
        NSLog(@"malloc %llu", ++mallocCount);
        dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
            free(test);
            NSLog(@"free %llu", ++freeCount);
        });
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
}
```

The console result:

```
...
2015-10-23 09:51:33.876 OS9MemoryTest[759:153135] malloc 220
2015-10-23 09:51:33.876 OS9MemoryTest[759:153133] free 220
2015-10-23 09:51:34.877 OS9MemoryTest[759:153135] malloc 221
2015-10-23 09:51:34.878 OS9MemoryTest[759:153133] free 221
2015-10-23 09:51:35.883 OS9MemoryTest[759:153135] malloc 222
2015-10-23 09:51:35.883 OS9MemoryTest[759:153133] free 222
```

Comment: You are calling `malloc` 60 times per second. Perhaps the overhead of dispatching the calls to `free` onto another queue result in less than 60 calls to `free` being made per second. So memory is being allocated faster than it is deallocated resulting in an eventual crash.

Comment: Hi, maybe you're right! I tried to put some NSLog in my code before, both of them are executed immediately and come in pair. But use dispatch_sync can solve this problem.

Comment: Now I use the dispatch_sync to avoid memory leak, but I still don't know why this only happened on iOS9?

Comment: Using `dispatch_sync` makes this whole thing kind of pointless. You now have some background queue. On this queue you loop forever. You call `malloc`, then you call `free` on the other queue while the "malloc" queue waits for that to finish. Then the "malloc" queue waits 1 second. What's the point of that?

Comment: The code I post is a simple version to reproduce this problem.  Actually I am not only calling free in the block, the serial queue is used for instead NSLock to do some memory sharing operations with other thread.

Comment: Hi, I finally figured out where the problem is. Thanks for your comment, it helps me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a better way to do this without leak problem rather than using dispatch_sync.

The point seems to be the setting of Quality of Service (QoS) class of serial queue.
Doing free in a queue which have QOS_CLASS_UNSPECIFIED QoS class causes this problem.

In my question, I free memory in a serial queue which was created by the following call :

```
dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
```

Its QoS setting is QOS_CLASS_UNSPECIFIED which causes this problem.

If create a serial queue with dispatch_queue_attr_t object, which have QoS setting excepted QOS_CLASS_UNSPECIFIED, the code runs perfectly without leaking:

```
- (void)threadWork {
    // Create a serial queue with QoS class.
    dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", attr);

    while (1) {
        // Do a simple malloc.
        int *foo = (int *)malloc(1024);

        // Do free in serial queue.
        dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
            free(foo);
        });

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0 / 60.0];
    }
}
```

I still don't understand why this problem would happened on iOS9,
but setting the QoS seems to make things work.